# Bootstrap Labels and Input not aligned horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I found an interesting problem when playing around with Bootstrap labels and inputs when in a form-inline class. The Labels seem to be adjusted slightly higher than the inputs. 
[image]

I'm just using basic razor html helpers to produce these inputs and an anchor tag for the Search.

```
<div class="form-inline">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartDate, "From:", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate, "MM-DD-YYYY", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "start-date" })
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.EndDate, "To:", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate, "MM-DD-YYYY", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @id = "end-date" })
<a id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Search</a>
```

Willing to propose new solutions to resolve this inline form group. But to me this looks annoying and unpleasing :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add some custom style, without bootstrap's default styling. Check this example:

```
<form>
<label for="email">Email address:</label>
<input type="email" class="xinput" id="email">

<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="password" class="xinput" id="pwd">

<button type="submit" class="xsubmit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

CSS:

```
label{border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;}
.xinput{height: 34px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;}
.xsubmit{height: 34px;
padding: 6px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555; border: none; outline: none; background-color: #008cba; color:    white;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elance/52VtD/15654/